# Task<IEnumerable<HttpContent>> vs Task<MultipartMemoryStreamProvider> in WebAPI file uploads

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, task

I am following some code that was written by an old colleague of mine some time ago to try and set up a file upload process with WebAPI.  In his code, the task that is created in the method signature is a task of type `Task<MultipartMemoryStreamProvider>` and in mine, it's of type `Task<IEnumerable<HttpContent>>`.

Because of this, Visual Studio 2010 is barking at me saying that task.Result.Contents won't work because task does not contain a definition for Result nor a definition for Contents.  It also says the return value wont' work because it wants to return void and I'm trying to return a response object.  Here is my method which is more or less and exact copy and paste from the sample I'm working with:

```
public Task<ImageResponseModel> Post()
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Must be multi-part request");
            }

            return Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                var model = new ImageModel();

                foreach (HttpContent content in task.Result.Contents)
                {
                    if (content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"UserName\"")
                    {
                        model.UserName = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"Caption\"")
                    {
                        model.Caption = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"Image\"")
                    {
                        model.Image = content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                    }
                }

                return DoEntry(model);
            });
        }

        [AcceptVerbs("")]
        public ImageResponseModel DoEntry(ImageModel model)
        {
            ImageResponseModel mod = new ImageResponseModel();

            return mod;
        }
```

ImageResponseModel is also essentially just a copy and paste from the sample which only has two properties with get/set.  ImageModel is also more or less just a copy and paste with three properties (two string properties and one byte[] property (for the actual file).

What am I doing wrong here?  Why does VS see his as a different Task<> type than mine?  How can I change mine to match his so that it will compile and work?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated my project in VS 2012 and it now works fine.  I think I must've had some old libraries in my 2010 installation.